# Create dates between two dates in Hive query(HQL) and later needs further transformation

Tags: sql, date, hive, formula, impala

Source
[image]

Desired Output
[image]

My desired output is Column D and C .
Formula column is for your help on how i did the calculation.
I am first trying to explode the dates based on min date and max date. Which i am not able to do.

I have also tried by join source table to a master calednar table. But there also i am not able to filter down to desired output.

```
Select Distinct mc.D, src.A From db.calendar mc LEFT JOIN db.source src ON mc.D= src.D;
```

For you help, my calendar table looks like this below
calendar
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will work in Hive, not Impala, because Impala does not support `lateral view posexplode`. Or maybe the latest Impala supports explode and row generation using joins, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381435/2700344) about Impala.

This is solution for Hive.

You do not need calendar, because missing dates can be generated using this approach:

`split(space(months_between(next_date, DT)),' ')` - this will create an array with size =  `months_between(next_date, DT)`

`posexplode()` will explode array and generate rows providing index i (starting from 0)

Then using index `i` and a bit modifyed formula you can calculate missing dates and amount. See DEMO:

```
with Source as (--source data, will work with more input dates
select '2023-06-30' as DT, 131234 as Amount union all
select '2023-12-31', 1243435 
) 

select last_day(add_months(DT, i)) as `Date`, --calculate date as start date+i (position from posexplode starts w 0)
       round(Amount + ((next_amount-Amount)/months_between(next_date, DT))*i,2) as Amount --formula
from
( --Get next_date to generate date range
select DT, Amount,
       lead(DT,1) over (order by DT) next_date,
       lead(Amount,1) over (order by DT) next_amount
  from Source s  
)s lateral view posexplode(split(space(months_between(next_date, DT)),' ')) e as i,x --generate rows
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------+
|Date      |Amount    |
+----------+----------+
|2023-06-30|131234.0  |
|2023-07-31|316600.83 |
|2023-08-31|501967.67 |
|2023-09-30|687334.5  |
|2023-10-31|872701.33 |
|2023-11-30|1058068.17|
|2023-12-31|1243435.0 |
+----------+----------+
```